# Speedstep shutting down notebook

Tags: laptop, shutdown, speedstep

I have an old notebook that is having problems regarding random shutdown, caused by speedstep

It is a Mirax PR6050 (MSI PR600 rebranded for BR market) with GM965 chipset

The CPU is a core2duo T8300 (2400Mhz) and originally it came with a core2duo T45450 (1.66 Mhz) and 4GB (2x2) 667Mhz RAM

I thought it was problems related to cooling, so I changed the fan and replaced the thermal paste (silver artic) to see if was a problem with temps, but since even with low temps (35 TO 45) it still shutdowns a lot at random times....

And of course, the same thing was happening when I was using the older CPU (1.66Mhz) and I changed the CPU thinking it was a CPU issue but even with a even lower CPU (1.500Mhz) it happens the same thing....

Any ideas how to fix that since when I disable speed step the core speed is cut by half ? It is supposed to run at 2400Mhz but it is working only at 1200Mhz

Tks

Comment: What makes you believe it is Speedstep shutting down your computer?

Comment: Hi
When I disable SpeedStep it does not reboot anymore
My laptop is on since yesterday and when I re-enabled SpeedStep it started to shutdown/reboot again...
tks

Comment: Have you checked for an update to your BIOS? Or have you reset your BIOS to defaults?

Comment: There is no more update for my BIOS
It is an old laptop
I tried to reset for default values but that did not help and I even took the CMOS battery off to hard-reset the BIOS and the same thing keeps happening, and its weird since i replaced the fan, put good thermal paste, and I even have an external fan plugged in the rear and a cooling base, and even so it keeps shutting off like if it was caused by overheat since it is not heating like that (I use coretemp to check and my AMD netbook that was cheaper gets more heat and does not do that...

Tks

Comment: BTW: If the CPU, chipset or mobo thinks the computer is overheat (by a faulty sensor, maybe) is it possible to turn off settings that make the computer shutdown for high heat ? I mean a way to do that in the OS, since my BIOS does not have advanced options

Tks

Comment: I was able to "fix" the issue inside Windows, but with Linux even without speedstep the OS shows full speed

Windows: Re-enabled speedstep at BIOS and disabled Intel PPM inside Windows using regedit and deleting a Windows driver )intelppm.sys

Linux: With speedstep disabled with shows full speed (2.4Mhz) but if I enbaled Speedstep it would have the same issue (shutdown)

Comment: Preventing a computer from shutting down for high-heat in the OS is going to depend on the capability of the hardware. The best protection for hardware is other hardware watching it, but some systems may allow the software some say in the matter. It will depend on the computer whether this is possible

Comment: Actually its not even hot, but it shutdowns anyway (like I said my AND netbook is hotter and it nver had any problem)
I was aBLE to delete intel speedstep driver from Windows and change settings so the OS would not be able to shut down and Windows is running at 2.4Mhz ate 40C - 50C, and I left my laptop on yesterday and it did not shutdown
But with Linux I cant find the correct name of the driver to do the same, and when I boot linux, the OS shutsdown the CPU

Comment: Have you tried a different flavor of Linux, perhaps one that's not trying so hard to manage things for you?

Comment: Yes
I installed Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Kali and they have the same behavior
And its weird: When I disable Speedstep at BIOS Linux shows the real speed (2400) with no problem, but Windows throttles it to 1200Mhz.
But if I enable speedstep Linux would shutdown....